# What is the difference between black and white square in notation?

Tags: notation

I'm reading a book on description logic and I found white and black squares at the end of some paragraphs. I would think they stand for Q.E.D., but since there are two types used in one book, I believe the black square states for something else. What could it be? Is there some convention for it?

(I checked and there is no list with explanation of symbols used in the book).

Comment: I’m not aware of any general convention; this sounds like a book-specific convention. I can imagine an author using one to mark the end of a proof and the other to mark the end of an example, or the end of the statement of a theorem whose proof is not given, but those are just guesses.

Comment: Or the end of a section/lemma of a proof.

Comment: Here you can find a more detailed answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979292/difference-between-square-and-blacksquare